# access base template variable from every template that extend it

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig, symfony4

In my base template, I have a list of object that I loop through to populate my navbar link to others templates. When I extend my base template with another template I have an error saying that this variable does not exist.

base.html.twig

```
<head>
  ....
</head>
<body>
  {% block navbar %}
     {% for e in event %}
         <li>
             <a href="/{{ e.getId() }}">{{ e.getName() }}</a>
         </li>
      {% endfor %}
  {% endblock %}
 </body>
```

What's the best way to use the event object in every controller/template ?

Comment: to avoid the error `{% if event is defined %}` then the for loop...

Comment: yes, this correct the error, but I obviously don't have any data in my navbar when i'm on another template that extend the base template. Cause event is not defined and i would like it to be

Comment: Typically you would do this sort of thing using a block: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/extends.html

Comment: I don't see how, my code for the events is already surrounded by a block, and I don't use that block in another template, so the event variable is always undefined in another template

Comment: In twig, variables don't get pushed up.  It's one of the many unfortunate consequences of templates not being objects.  You can take a look at how projects like KnpMenuBundle does it.  The cleanest way is to use an [embedded controller](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html).  That saves you from having to inject event into all your templates.  Otherwise just include a menubar template in your active template.